# Javascript kit slider touch not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, slider

I'm trying to adding a post slider to the mobile version of my [website](https://amccbeauty.com/)

The website is built on Laravel and I've added a slider script taken from [here,](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml) however it's not responding to touch.

Any ideas how I can configure the code to get it working properly?

Here's the code I have:

**home.mobile.blade**

```html
<section class="articlesWrapper">
  <div class="articles" id="articles-swipezone">
    <div class="wrapper">
      @foreach ($articles as $article)
      <a href="{{ $article->url }}" class="article">
        <div class="titleWrapper">
          <h3 class="title">{{ prop_trans($article, 'title') }}</h3>
        </div>
        <img src="{{ $article->media->url }}" class="thumb" />
        <span class="description">
                    @if (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::isLocale('en'))
                                {{ mb_substr(trim(strip_tags(prop_trans($article, 'html'))), 0, 50) }}...
                            @elseif (\Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::isLocale('cn'))
                                {{ mb_substr(trim(strip_tags(prop_trans($article, 'html'))), 0, 30) }}...
                            @endif
                </span>
      </a>
      @endforeach
    </div>
  </div>


  <ul class="slide-indicators2">
    @for ($i = 0; $i
    < count($articles); $i++) <li class="slide-indicator2 @if ($i == 0) active @endif">
      </li>
      @endfor
  </ul>
</section>
@endsection
```

**home.js**

Below contains the js code responsible for the touch/swipe event.

```js
// credit: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml
function swipedetect(el, callback) {

  var touchsurface = el,
    swipedir,
    startX,
    startY,
    distX,
    distY,
    threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
    restraint = 100, // maximum distance allowed at the same time in perpendicular direction
    allowedTime = 300, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
    elapsedTime,
    startTime,
    handleswipe = callback || function(swipedir) {}

  touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
    swipedir = 'none'
    dist = 0
    startX = touchobj.pageX
    startY = touchobj.pageY
    startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
    e.preventDefault()
  }, false)

  touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
  }, false)

  touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
    var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
    distX = touchobj.pageX - startX // get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    distY = touchobj.pageY - startY // get vertical dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
    if (elapsedTime <= allowedTime) { // first condition for awipe met
      if (Math.abs(distX) >= threshold && Math.abs(distY) <= restraint) { // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
        swipedir = (distX < 0) ? 'left' : 'right' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
      } else if (Math.abs(distY) >= threshold && Math.abs(distX) <= restraint) { // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
        swipedir = (distY < 0) ? 'up' : 'down' // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
      }
    }
    handleswipe(swipedir)
    e.preventDefault()
  }, false)
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  SlideShow.init();

  var curPos = 0;
  var maxPos = $(".articles .article").length;
  var el = document.getElementById('articles-swipezone');
  swipedetect(el, function(swipeDir) {
    console.log("TOUCH DETECTED");
    var swipe = false;
    if (swipeDir == "left" && curPos < maxPos) {
      curPos++;
      swipe = true;
    } else if (swipeDir == "right" && curPos > 0) {
      curPos--;
      swipe = true;
    }

    if (swipe == true) {
      $(".articlesWrapper .slide-indicator2").removeClass("active");
      $(".articlesWrapper .slide-indicator2").eq(curPos).addClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify: What is the code that is suppose to react to the "touch"

Comment: @DaniDev edited the post for clarification, sorry this is one of my first questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Fixed it, had to add clearfix class to the wrapper 

so  <div class="wrapper clearfix">